# Audio Playback Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

When Ever I try to play music with my application in the simulator I don't get any sound

```
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!)
      
      guard let player = player else {
         print("player is nil")
            return
      }
```

In my debug console I get urlstring is nil no matter where I put the MP3

`let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: song.trackName, ofType: "mp3")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "example.mp3", ofType:nil)!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure target membership is ticked for your file and use

```
 let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "example", withExtension:"mp3")!
```